Jetpack Compose Icon Button in TextField Decorator Not Being Recomposed
I'm having an issue with my text field icon that's nested in the decorator. It's not being updated when isPasswordVisible changes. However, the obfuscation part is updated when isPasswordVisible changes. I put logs right before the IconButton and it doesn't get reached when isPasswordVisible changes.
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PasswordTextField(
    state: TextFieldState,
    isPasswordVisible: Boolean,
    onTogglePasswordVisibility: () -> Unit,
    hint: String,
    title: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var isFocused by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            if (title != null) {
                Text(
                    text = title,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall,
                )
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
        BasicSecureTextField(
            state = state,
            textObfuscationMode = if (isPasswordVisible) {
                TextObfuscationMode.Visible
            } else TextObfuscationMode.Hidden,
            textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
            ),
            cursorBrush = SolidColor(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground),
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                .background(
                    MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
                )
                .border(
                    width = 1.dp,
                    color = Color.Transparent,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
                )
                .padding(12.dp)
                .onFocusChanged {
                    isFocused = it.isFocused
                },
            decorator = { innerBox ->
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = PasswordIcon,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                    ) {
                        if (state.text.isEmpty() && !isFocused) {
                            Text(
                                text = hint,
                                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(
                                    alpha = 0.4f
                                ),
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                            )
                        }
                        innerBox()
                    }

                    IconButton(
                        onClick = onTogglePasswordVisibility,
                        modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp)
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = if (isPasswordVisible) {
                                EyeOpenIcon
                            } else {
                                EyeCloseIcon
                            },
                            contentDescription = if (isPasswordVisible) {
                                stringResource(id = R.string.show_password)
                            } else {
                                stringResource(id = R.string.hide_password)
                            },
                            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}


That seems to be a bug in the BasicSecureTextField. In the current stable version 1.6.8 I can reproduce the problem, in the current beta 1.7.0-beta04 it is fixed.
Upgrading to non-stable versions is not officially supported by Google when using the Compose Bom, so you must either use some third-party Bom, like https://github.com/chrisbanes/compose-bom/?tab=readme-ov-file, or revert back to explicitly specifying the version of each Compose artifact.
When you upgrade, be aware that BasicSecureTextField changed its package, so you need to adjust your import statements.

Thank you, I think I'm going to try a work-around for now. I did try that third-party Bom but I still got that issue. Looking through their changelog, it seems like the latest version they have is 1.7.0-beta02.
